# Uploading Image in Classic ASP and Image not found in the directory

Tags: image, file-upload, asp-classic

I am trying to upload a image in classic asp and am using below code for the same.

```
file_path  = "/uploads/events/upload_img"
img_folder = Server.MapPath(file_path)

Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Upload.CodePage = 949
Upload.SetMaxSize (500 * 1024), True
Upload.OverwriteFiles = false
Upload.CreateDirectory img_folder, True
Upload.save

Upload.Files("img1")
```

Here `img1` contains the image taken from user through:

```
<input type="file" name="img1" />
```

However it executes correctly but image is not seen in the folder  `/uploads/events/upload_img`

Can anyone tell me why this is? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the `save()` method with no parameters, the file is being uploaded to the server's memory, not to a folder.

Try this:

```
img_folder = Server.MapPath("/uploads/events/upload_img")

Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Upload.CodePage = 949
Upload.SetMaxSize (500 * 1024), True
Upload.OverwriteFiles = false
Upload.CreateDirectory img_folder, True
Upload.Save(img_folder)

uploadedImg = Upload.Files("img1")
```

Here's a link to the [Save() method](http://www.aspupload.com/object_upload.html#Save) in the Persits.Upload object reference.

Comment: Note that you need `Server.MapPath` to convert a relative path to an absolute path for this function. Use `Upload.SaveVirtual` to work with a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works.  Just post to it from a multipart-form.

```
=========================
EXAMPLE MULTIPART FORM
=========================

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<input type="file" name="img1" /><input type="submit" />
</form>

=========
ASP CODE
=========

Set Upload = Server.CreateObject("Persits.Upload")
Upload.CodePage = 949              
Upload.SetMaxSize (500 * 1024), True
Upload.OverwriteFiles = False ' Generate unique names
Upload.Save "C:\path\filename.jpg"

Set File = Upload.Files(1)
uploadedImg = File.ExtractFileName

Set Upload = Nothing
Set File = Nothing
```